# minimal hardware requirements for Android

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum specifications for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/what-are-the-minimum-specifications-for-android)

I would like to know the minimum hardware (memory, CPU) to run Android, good documentation is also a good answer.

Versions : gingerbread or ice cream sandwich

Answer (score 3):

According to an interview with Andy Rubin in 2008 this is the minimum requirements for android:

- 32 MB RAM
- 32 MB Flash Memory
- 200 MHz processor

[[Source](http://www.mycomputeraid.com/computers/google-android-system-requirements/)]
[[Source 2](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f8/whats-the-basic-hardware-requirement-for-a-android-phone-95/)]

For gingerbread, I could not find anything official, but I found a few sites that say the following:

- 1GHz processor
- 512MB Ram
- 3.5 inches or more screen size

[[Source](http://techie-buzz.com/mobile-news/android-30-gingerbread-minimum-system-requirements.html)]

I also found an "official looking" site that has requirements, but this looks to be a couple years old and doesn't say what version of android this is spec'd for.

- ARM-based chipset
- 128 MB RAM
- 256 MB Flash External
- QVGA TFT LCD or larger, 16-bit color or better

[[Source](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/system_requirements.html)]

Comment: The 1 GHz requirement for Gingerbread is more of a myth than a fact, I think. The LG Optimus S got the Gingerbread update and it has a 600 MHz processor. It seems like all of the popular phones were at the 1 GHz mark so it became a commonly-cited "requirement". That site also refers to GB as "Android 3.0"...